# How to retrive the selected grid rows inside a panel in controller in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

how can i retrive the selected rows from grid inside the panel in controller i tried using itemId but i am getting the null array. I attaching the screenshot of grid. Also i pasting the constoller selection method

```
Ext.widget('adminRoleView').down('#adminRoleView').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

"adminRoleView" is the alias of the panel and "adminRoleView" is the itemId of the grid which is inside the panel. Also i am new to technology so i dont know whether this wrong or right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
var rows = Ext.getCmp('YOUR_GRID_ID').getSelectionModel().getSelections();
```

its return all the selected rows.

Comment: but container in extjs grid or not

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution by giving

```
this.up("panel").down("itemID").getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

i think Ext.ComponentMgr is good than above method... :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Ext.getCmp('adminRoleView').getStore().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

Comment: The same answer as the above one

Comment: well @Aminesrine, if you read closely, the .getStore() part might be very important. Thank you for your wise comment !